# Openstack noVNC console is slow

Tags: console, openstack

I am running some VMs on my openstack packstack train release, when i run a vm without GUI everything works fine, once i use a vm with a GUI (like ubunut, centos) i don't know why it becomes extremely slow and it's blocking me from advancing on my work, i checked the resource of each vm, of my server too, and they all have sufficient resources. is this a problem with noVNC ? or what ? note that i  tried to access with all the nvaigators but the problem is always not solved !
Is there any help, please ?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, did u figure out any way to solve it ?

Comment: @Rafik  yes i changed the hypervisor from QEMU to KVM and it worked !

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I also changed the hypervisor from qemu to kvm, but when I log into the console from horizon dashboard, the mouse cursor is too slow!

Comment: have you tried to change the navigator that you are using, or if you have sufficient ressources ?